# jQuery wrapping deferred and promises

Tags: jquery, promise, deferred

I have a jq replacement of the standard confirm dialog.

I am allowing the user to pass in a function that will be called if the user clicks on ok.

The passed in function may call a long running async task like an ajax call, sometimes not, I want to cater for both.

I used this solution as a base (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374933)

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
MyConfirmation('A Title', 'A message to the user', function() {
    $.get('/some/bigdata/longrunning');
}
).then(function() {
    // add to dom here
});
```

This is MyConfirmation:

```
MyConfirmation = function (title, message, ok) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $('<div/>')
        .text(message)
        .dialog({
                    buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    if($.isFunction(ok)) {
                        ok.apply();
                    }
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    d.resolve(true);
                    return true;
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    d.resolve(false);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).remove();
            },
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 'auto',
            title: title,
            modal: true
        });

    return d.promise();
};
```

I want to ideally combine with my deferred which returns true or false to indicate if the user clicked ok or cancel.

I know I can use the .done method on the promise returned from $.get but how would I make my solution work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am allowing the user to pass in a function that will be called if the user clicks on ok.

Don't. Just remove that `ok` parameter from the `MyConfirmation` function, and only return the promise for the button clicks. The user can then chain his function on that if he wants - or do even more.

Your call should rather look like this:

```
MyConfirmation('A Title', 'A message to the user').then(function(okPressed) {
    if (okPressed)
        return $.get('/some/bigdata/longrunning');
}).then(function(longruningResult) {
    // add to dom here
});
```

You might also `reject()` the promise when the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button is pressed, then you don't need that boolean `okPressed` check and could use a separate error handler instead.

Comment: I was **just** about to mark my own answer as accepted and then read this much more elegant solution. Plus I learned something from this as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the ajax call as a returned promise :

```
MyConfirmation('A Title', 'A message to the user', function() {
    return $.get('/some/bigdata/longrunning');
}
).then(function() {
    // add to dom here
});
```

MyConfirmation function:

```
MyConfirmation = function (title, message, ok) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $('<div/>')
        .text(message)
        .dialog({
                    buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    if($.isFunction(ok)) {
                        ok().then(function() {
                            d.resolve(true);
                        });
                    }
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    d.resolve(false);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).remove();
            },
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 'auto',
            title: title,
            modal: true
        });

    return d.promise();
};
```

This adds a condition to resolve the dialog deffered, from the ajax promise itself

Disclaimer : untested :)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Pandaiolo's response, I realised I was supposed to return the ajax call in my calling function. That and the chaining of my own deferred when the passed in function completed.

A small tweak to catch those instances when the passed in function does not return a deferred (by using `$.when`) and it works (see [How can I determine if a jQuery object is deferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965065/how-can-i-determine-if-a-jquery-object-is-deferred))

MyConfirmation becomes:

```
MyConfirmation = function (title, message, ok) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $('<div/>')
        .text(message)
        .dialog({
                    buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    if($.isFunction(ok)) {
                        $.when(ok.apply()).then(function() {
                            d.resolve(true);
                        });
                    } else {
                        d.resolve(true);
                    }
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    d.resolve(false);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).remove();
            },
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 'auto',
            title: title,
            modal: true
        });

    return d.promise();
};
```